# the select query based on distinct date is not displaying any results

Tags: oracle, jsp

This is the jsp page which is not displaying any result for the query in the variable `PreparedStatement pst`, below is the jsp page attached and the description of the table CD from which records have to be fetched. How to correct it?

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page session="true" import="java.util.*, 
shopping.CD,java.sql.*,shopping.getParam" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#33CCFF">

   <center>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td><b>ALBUM</b></td>
<td><b>ARTIST</b></td>
<td><b>COUNTRY</b></td>
<td><b>PRICE</b></td>
<td><b>QUANTITY</b></td>

<td></td>
</tr>

user is :<%= session.getAttribute("username")%> 
<%     



try
{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:xe","xyz","xyz");
Statement st= conn.createStatement();


ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select distinct(TRUNC(DATEBOUGHT)) FROM CD where User_name='"+session.getAttribute("username")+"' AND STATUS IS NOT NULL ");
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("select Album,Artist,Country,Price,Quantity,Status from CD where Status='final' AND User_name='"+session.getAttribute("username")+"' AND DATEBOUGHT=?");
java.sql.Date str;
 while(rs.next())
 {
   str = rs.getDate (1);
  out.print(str); 
  pst.setDate(1,str);
  ResultSet rs1= pst.executeQuery();
  while(rs1.next())
  {
 %>
<tr>
<td><b><%= rs1.getString(1) %></b></td>
<td><b><%= rs1.getString(2) %></b></td>
<td><b><%= rs1.getString(3) %></b></td>
<td><b><%= rs1.getString(4) %></b></td>
<td><b><%= rs1.getString(5) %></b></td>

<td>

<% } }%>
</table>

</center>
<% 
} catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
                        out.println(e.getMessage());
}

%>

</body>
</html>
```

---

```
Name       Null? Type         
---------- ----- ------------ 
ALBUM            VARCHAR2(40) 
ARTIST           VARCHAR2(40) 
COUNTRY          VARCHAR2(40) 
PRICE            VARCHAR2(40) 
QUANTITY         VARCHAR2(40) 
TOTALCOST        VARCHAR2(40) 
USER_NAME        VARCHAR2(30) 
STATUS           VARCHAR2(7)  
DATEBOUGHT       DATE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query is:

```
select distinct(TRUNC(DATEBOUGHT))
FROM   CD
where  User_name='"+session.getAttribute("username")+"'
AND    STATUS IS NOT NULL
```

There are a couple of issues with this:

- First, `DISTINCT` is a keyword and not a function.
- Second, why are you using bind variables later in your code but not when you are passing the username?

But back on to why it is not working, the second query is:

```
select Album,
       Artist,
       Country,
       Price,
       Quantity,
       Status
from   CD
where  Status='final'
AND    User_name='"+session.getAttribute("username")+"'
AND    DATEBOUGHT=?
```

You are comparing `DATEBOUGHT` and the value from the first query which is `TRUNC( DATEBOUGHT )` - they are never going to match unless the `DATEBOUGHT` value is on the stroke of midnight.

You could use:

```
AND    TRUNC(DATEBOUGHT)=?
```

Or, you could rewrite both queries into a single query. Something like this:

```
select Album,
       Artist,
       Country,
       Price,
       Quantity,
       Status
FROM   (
  SELECT c.*,
         COUNT( status ) OVER ( PARTITION BY TRUNC( datebought ) ) AS ct
  from   CD
  WHERE  User_name=?
)
WHERE  Status='final'
AND    ct > 0
```

However, the `Status='final'` filter will only be true when `ct > 0` so having both seems redundant so I am unsure why you require the first query at all.